# Cannot call Jump Game function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

so I am doing a Jump game, you can see task here: [Jump game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NTxa.png)

So I found a lot of solutions and they have no errors, but the thing that whenever i call a function, in webpage i see only blank page. I want to see just simple text "you won" or "you lost". What I did wrong here? Function is good, no errors. Maybe problem that i don't know how to call this function or numbers should be in array somehow? Here is my code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>Jump Game</title>

    <style>
        * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        canvas {
            background: "#eee";
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
            border: 2px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var canJump = function(nums) {
            if (nums.length < 2) {
                return true;
            }
            for (let i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++) {
                if (i + nums[i] >= nums.length - 1) {
                    return true;
                };
                if (nums[i] === 0) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (i + nums[i] > i + 1 + nums[i + 1]) {
                    nums[i + 1] = nums[i] - 1;
                };
            };
        };

        if(canJump(1,2,3,4) === true) {
            document.write("you won");
        }
        else if(canJump(1,2,3,4) === false) {
            document.write("you lost");
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Please help me.

Comment: *"or numbers should be in array somehow"* Yes, they should. Currently `canJump` returns `undefined` for the input you provide which doesn't satisfy any of your conditions.

Comment: A few other tips. Avoid `document.write()` - it's archaic. Much better to use DOM-scripting to inject content into the page. Also, avoid writing to the outer scope i.e. creating global variables. Run your code inside a closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if(canJump(1,2,3,4) === true)` ... should be `if(canJump([1,2,3,4]) === true)`.

Comment: Thank you !, could you tell me how can I do that user would choose numbers for game, not me?

Comment: That obviously depends on how exactly the users are selecting the numbers. But you'll need to store the selected numbers in a variable:
`var selectedNumbers = []`
Somehow push new numbers onto the array when they're selected:
`selectedNumbers.push(newNumber)`
and then use it:
`canJump(selectedNumbers)`

Comment: I wrote this code: `
var howMuchNumbers = prompt("How much numbers you will pick for game?");
        var selectedNumbers = [];
        for(var i = 1;i<=howMuchNumbers;i++)
        {

            var newNumbers = prompt("Pick a number");
            selectedNumbers.push(newNumbers);

        }

        if (canJump([selectedNumbers]) === true) {
                console.log(selectedNumbers + "you won");
        } else if (canJump([selectedNumbers]) === false) {
                console.log(selectedNumbers + "you lost");
        }
` but now it always winning. why?:(

Comment: Try removing the square brackets in your function call. I.e. `canJump([selected numbers])` should be `canJump(selected numbers)`